# C++ DLL to be used in C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, c++, dll, graphviz

I am very new to C++ programming...

I was assigned an assignment to do a SkipList in C++ that will do some functionalities..
Apart from these functionalities, there was also the following included:

> Export the Skip List to a .DOT file that can be rendered in GraphViz

Any ideas how I can do this?
Also, I need to export the DLL so that I can use it in either Java or else in C#..

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can compare it to the ConcurrentSkipListMap in Java already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to use C++ code in Java, check out [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI). It requires you to modify your C++ code with JNI wrappers (see the Wikipedia link for examples).

C#, on the other hand, can call DLL functions which are exported normally, i.e. with `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`, via [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks mate .. i will using what you said.. so using PInvoke, i will create a .DOT file ?

Comment: DOT files and GraphViz are unrelated to DLL creation and usage. It sounds like that's something your assignment expects your code to do.

Comment: @user1317277 No problem. Here's something a quick Google searched turned up about GraphViz DOT files: http://www.graphviz.org/pub/scm/graphviz2/doc/info/lang.html

Answer (score 1):

The Java has got a JNI technology
In fact it's c/c++(with extern "c" calls) library with some specific types and rules

And yes you can use your dll in Java with some jni bridge